# Rails - render command breaks line after label

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following the official [rails tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).

I have the `render 'new'` command in my article_controller. If I give an invalid input (too short), the new article page gets re-rendered. 
However, now saving the invalid value the render puts a line break before my title text field.

[image: Before]
[image: After]

```
<h1>New Article</h1>

<%= form_for :article, url: articles_path do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %> <-NO BREAK HERE!
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

As you can see I intentionally left out the first `<br>` tag after the title's label to see the difference.

What is the story behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Rails wraps invalid fields in div. Ordinary fields like:

```
<label for="foo">Email: </label>
<input type="bar" value="fubar" name="baz[bar]" id="baz_bar">
```

Will become wrapped in div class="field_with_errors" by default when those fields have invalid values

```
<div class="field_with_errors">
  <label for="foo">Email: </label>
</div> 
<div class="field_with_errors">
  <input type="bar" value="fubar" name="baz[bar]" id="baz_bar">
</div>
```

The way your div's are styled (or not), influences how this is displayed. Probably by default, the divs will try and be rendered one below the other, that's why you're getting a line break there.

You can more read about it here and see how you can override this behaviour
https://rubyplus.com/articles/3401-Customize-Field-Error-in-Rails-5